# upload video in grocery crud

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, file-upload, grocery-crud

I facing the problem in grocery crud while uploading a video file.  During upload process it's shows process image after finished that it's shows blank and video file doesn't upload. I already set 777 permission to my upload folder and I try to upload mp4, flv, 3gp file formats.

Here is my PHP code

```
function test_video(){
    $crud=new grocery_CRUD();
    $crud->set_table('test');
    $crud->set_subject('Test Video');
    $crud->set_field_upload('url', 'assets/uploads');

    $output=$crud->render();        
    $this->_crud_output($output);
}
```

My DB structure is

title varchar(50), 
url text

And I already gave 777 permission to uploads folder.

Thanx

Comment: post your code to see if it has an error

Answer (score 2):

I have ran into same problem and what i did was increasing the php upload limit in .htaccess.

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 500M

php_value post_max_size 400M
```

But i didn't stop here,Now after upload the "grocery crud list" shows video as a file link,
So i added a column call back, and integrated a play button.

```
$crud -> callback_column('video_file_name', array($this, '_video_player'));

function _video_player($value, $row) {

    return "<a href='#' id='".$row -> video_id."' class='btn btn-sucess video_play'>Play</a>";
}
```

Hope you understand what am saying.